# Create a Logger for an object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, logging

I want to write a logger that takes one object argument (build-in or user-defined) and returns new object which acts as argument and has the same methods, and also each method call is logged in browser console.

For example:

```
var a = [];
var b = myLogger(a);
b.push("foo");
< array.push("foo") -> 1;
b.push("bar");
< array.push("bar") -> 2;
```

As far as I understand I need to create a decorator to solve this. Is this right way to solve this task? Any other suggestions are also appreciated.

Comment: You can do this with [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) in modern browsers.

Answer (score 0):

```
function myLogger (target) {
  var handler = {
    get(target, name){
      var result = name in target? target[name] : undefined;
      console.log(`< ${JSON.stringify(target)}.${name} -> ${result}`);
      return result;
    }
  };
  return new Proxy(target, handler);
}

var a = { x: 1};
var a_Proxy = myLogger(a);

a_Proxy.x; // logs < {"x":1}.x -> 1
```

use can use ES6 "Proxy" standard built-in object.
https://developer.mozilla.org/ko/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy